# Java-level deadlock in java.lang.Class.getMethods - CentOS-7.2

Tags: java, multithreading, centos, classloader

I was trying to display all method name for a class. 
This code works fine in sent os 6,

```
private static void extractClassMethods(Class classObject) {     

    // read the methods
    Method[] methods = classObject.getMethods();

    // no methods
    if (methods == null) {
        return;
    }

    // print method path
    for (Method method : methods) {  
        System.out.println(method.getName()) ;
    } 
}
```

Find the complete exception log,

## Found one Java-level deadlock:

"Thread-24":
  waiting to lock monitor 0x00007fee807b66b8 (object 0x00000007e060e490, a org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader),
  which is held by "Thread-15"
"Thread-15":
  waiting to lock monitor 0x00007feebc0101c8 (object 0x00000007e12564e8, a java.lang.Object),
  which is held by "Start Level Event Dispatcher"
"Start Level Event Dispatcher":
  waiting to lock monitor 0x00007fee807b66b8 (object 0x00000007e060e490, a org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader),
  which is held by "Thread-15"

## Java stack information for the threads listed above:

"Thread-24":
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:424)
    - waiting to lock <0x00000007e060e490> (a org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:413)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:189)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:405)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:357)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:83)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2531)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2651)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1467)
    at com.something.extractClassMethods(MethodAccessManager.java:102) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
"Thread-15":
    at com.eclipsesource.jaxrs.publisher.internal.JAXRSConnector.addResource(JAXRSConnector.java:110)
    - waiting to lock <0x00000007e12564e8> (a java.lang.Object)
    at com.eclipsesource.jaxrs.publisher.internal.ResourceTracker.delegateAddService(ResourceTracker.java:45)
    at com.eclipsesource.jaxrs.publisher.internal.ResourceTracker.addingService(ResourceTracker.java:39)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.trackAdding(ServiceTracker.java:1064)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.track(ServiceTracker.java:1042)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.serviceChanged(ServiceTracker.java:975)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:1224)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:195)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.publishServiceEventPrivileged(Framework.java:1603)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.publishServiceEvent(Framework.java:1578)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.ServiceRegistrationImpl.(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.createServiceRegistration(BundleContextImpl.java:657)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:609)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:675) 
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$2.run(BundleContextImpl.java:999)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:993)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:974)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:346)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:189)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:405)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:357)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:83)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358) 
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$2.run(BundleContextImpl.java:999)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:993)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:974)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:346)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:189)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:405)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:357)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:83)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2531)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2651)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1467)
    at com.something.extractClassMethods(MethodAccessManager.java:102 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
"Start Level Event Dispatcher":
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2531)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1855)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller$2.run(IntrospectionModeller.java:236)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller.getAllDeclaredMethods(IntrospectionModeller.java:230)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller.checkForNonPublicMethodIssues(IntrospectionModeller.java:170)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller.doCreateResourceBuilder(IntrospectionModeller.java:118)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller.access$000(IntrospectionModeller.java:80)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller$1.call(IntrospectionModeller.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller$1.call(IntrospectionModeller.java:108)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:255)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller.createResourceBuilder(IntrospectionModeller.java:108)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.Resource.from(Resource.java:744)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:411)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.access$500(ApplicationHandler.java:163)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.run(ApplicationHandler.java:323)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$2.call(Errors.java:289)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$2.call(Errors.java:286)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:286)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.(ApplicationHandler.java:320)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.(ApplicationHandler.java:285)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.(WebComponent.java:310)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.reload(ServletContainer.java:578)
    at com.eclipsesource.jaxrs.publisher.internal.JerseyContext.addResource(JerseyContext.java:71)
    at com.eclipsesource.jaxrs.publisher.internal.JAXRSConnector.registerResource(JAXRSConnector.java:140)
    at com.eclipsesource.jaxrs.publisher.internal.JAXRSConnector.registerResource(JAXRSConnector.java:122)
    at com.eclipsesource.jaxrs.publisher.internal.JAXRSConnector.doAddResource(JAXRSConnector.java:116)
    at com.eclipsesource.jaxrs.publisher.internal.JAXRSConnector.addResource(JAXRSConnector.java:110)
    - locked <0x00000007e12564e8> (a java.lang.Object)
    at com.eclipsesource.jaxrs.publisher.internal.ResourceTracker.delegateAddService(ResourceTracker.java:45)
    at com.eclipsesource.jaxrs.publisher.internal.ResourceTracker.addingService(ResourceTracker.java:39)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.trackAdding(ServiceTracker.java:1064)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.trackInitialServices(ServiceTracker.java:926)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker.open(ServiceTracker.java:330)
    - locked <0x00000007e1256ab8> (a com.eclipsesource.jaxrs.publisher.internal.ResourceTracker)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker.open(ServiceTracker.java:274)
    at com.eclipsesource.jaxrs.publisher.internal.Activator.openAllServiceTracker(Activator.java:76)
    at com.eclipsesource.jaxrs.publisher.internal.Activator.start(Activator.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$2.run(BundleContextImpl.java:999)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:993)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:974)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:346)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.update.internal.configurator.ConfigurationActivator.installBundles(ConfigurationActivator.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.update.internal.configurator.ConfigurationActivator.start(ConfigurationActivator.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$2.run(BundleContextImpl.java:999)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:993)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:974)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:346)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:350)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1118)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:631)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:279)
    - locked <0x00000007e40c67c0> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:465)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:195)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:297)

Found 1 deadlock.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine 
There is other problem as exception stack start from org.eclipse.osgi.framework
also your code working fine at my side.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, The above mentioned code is called from an activator of a maven bundle. this particular code exist in a separate jar file. This code works fine in centos 6.

Comment: I solved the problem by avoiding multi-thread. I was calling the above method by spanning different thread for each class.